# RecurrenceTable of a piecewise recurrence function

Tags: recursion, piecewise

How to can I get `RecurrenceTable` to deal with a piecewise function?

For example,

$
\qquad x_{n+1}= x_n(1.5-0.5x_n)\qquad \text{if $x_n\ge0.5$}\\
\qquad x_{n+1}= x_n(0.5+0.5x_n)\qquad \text{if $x_n<0,5$}\\
\qquad x_0=0.2
$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. I have the impression that there's something wrong in your equations, please check them. As they are, they do not define a recursion.

Comment: I asked that meaning: we may write that x[n+1]=x[n](1,5-0,5x[n]) if x[n]>=0,5; x[n+1]=x[n](0,5+0,5x[n]) if x[n]<0,5, x[0]==0.2

Comment: Just edit your question to reflect what you just wrote.

Comment: All values $x(n)$ are less that 0.5 in your example, so the case distinction is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is similar to @Roman's, but uses a simpler version of `Piecewise` and is set for easy variation of both `x[1]` and `max`.

```
With[{x1 = .75, nmax = 8},
  RecurrenceTable[
    {x[n + 1] == Piecewise[{{x[n] (1 - x[n])/2, x[n] < 1/2}}, x[n] (3 - x[n])/2], 
     x[1] == x1},
    x, {n, nmax}]]
```

> `{0.75, 0.84375, 0.909668, 0.950754, 0.974164, 0.986748, 0.993286, 0.996621}`

Comment: Thank you a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
RecurrenceTable[{x[0] == 0.2,
  x[n + 1] == Piecewise[{{x[n] (3/2 - 1/2 x[n]), x[n] >= 1/2},
                         {x[n] (1/2 + 1/2 x[n]), x[n] < 1/2}}]},
  x[n], {n, 0, 10}]
```

> {0.2, 0.12, 0.0672, 0.0358579, 0.0185719, 0.00945838, 0.00477392, 0.00239836, 0.00120205, 0.00060175, 0.000301056}